# Java IO's implements on thread variable sharing

Tags: java, multithreading

I was confused with a code snippet like this:

```
public class LearnTest {

private static boolean tag = true;
private static int i = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (tag) {
                //System.out.println("ok");
                i++;
            }
        }
    }).start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    tag = false;
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

In the code, we have a `new-thread` and `main-thread`.The result about this code will be a random value of `i` and the `new-thread` will not exit.Because `new-thread` will not get the new  `tag` value.

if we change the define of `tag` which will be decorated with `volatile`, it will print some value of `i` and `new-thread` will exit. Because `volatile` will keep the visibility for all thread.

But when I cannel the comment for the commentted code line,and the`tag` will not be decorated witch `volatile`,it will print some "ok" and exit.

why?

what I suppose is that Java's IO will do something like `synchronized`, it will force the `tag` side value of `new-thread` to refresh from main shared memory.

This's corret?

Comment: If you not define as `volatile`, the variable __maybe__ cached by CPU, and maybe NOT, so it no strange if other thread can see it's change.

Answer (score 0):

Without `volatile` the thread is not *guaranteed* to see changes to the value. It *may* see them.

In this case adding the `System.out.println()` results (apparently) in the value being removed from the cache, so it's fetched from the main memory at some point. Without the `println()` the value remains in cache, and you get the infinite (or at least very long) loop.

That's one difficulty with concurrent programming, sometimes code may *appear* to work correctly, but there's no way to be certain it *always* works correctly.